# Use Facebook GraphAPI or FQL to get Facebook activity log

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I can explore my activity log using browser
(https://www.facebook.com/help/437430672945092)

I wants to write a app to analyze my facebook data.

Is there any way to get my activity log using GraphAPI or FQL?

Comment: I believe that would be against user privacy policy (accessing complete archive of a user) but you can use the other API calls to achieve this

Comment: Now I can get all my like activity. Is there any way to get all my comment activtity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible, but not via a single request of query. It's neccessary to use a combination of both Graph API requests, as well as FQL queries. You'll need the appropriate Access Token Permissions to do this.

All of your Posts:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/posts?since=UNIX_TIMESTAMP&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

All of your OpenGraph Actions. This can get lengthy, see the list at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph Example for the og.likes:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/og.likes?since=UNIX_TIMESTAMP&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

For custom OpenGraph Actions, you have to create the queries depending on the definition of the Actions. See docs here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects#read Sample for Foursquare Checkins:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/playfoursquare:checkin_to?since=UNIX_TIMESTAMP&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

All of your Object Likes (FQL):

```
select object_id from like where user_id = me()
```

All of your URL Likes (FQL):

```
select url from url_like where user_id = me()
```

All of your Page Likes (FQL):

```
select page_id, name, categories from page where page_id in (select page_id from page_fan where uid = me())
```

I'm sure that I forgot some, but I think the message is here that it's not really simple and there's not a "all-in-one" query which can do what you want to achieve.

Comment: thanks,  Is there any way to get all my comment activtity?
something like xxx commented on a post

Comment: I don't know of a simple solution.

Comment: FQL: SELECT text, fromid FROM comment WHERE post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE filter_key IN (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me()) AND actor_id IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=me()) order by created_time) 
can select comments on the post in my newsfeed, so I add the condition "AND fromid=me()" at the end  in order to fetch comments by me, but result is empty...