# Facebook Graph API - How to get everything I have liked?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am new to the API. I tried /me/likes in the graph explorer, it returns only the pages that I like (rightfully so according to the api reference). However, I'd like to get everything - namely posts, photos, statuses, etc - that I have liked.

Any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe it is possible to get what you are asking for with the Graph API.  A good way to see what query to use to get data is to first look at the website and mobile apps to see if they present the data you want.  This is because the website and mobile apps will use the Graph API or FQL to retrieve data when it is available through those sources.  So all you would need to do is go to the page that contains data that you want and then using a network traffic capture tool (like Fiddler) you can see what requests are being made to get the data.

It turns out that there is a page on the website that displays all of the objects that a User has Liked.  To see this, select "Activity Log" in the drop down on the right-most side of the FB toolbar.  Then select "Likes" from the left side column.  This view will display the data that you are looking for.  Unfortunately, to get this data the app makes a request to:

```
https://www.facebook.com/123456/allactivity?privacy_source=activity_log&log_filter=likes
```

Where "123456" is the FB UserId.  What is returned is an HTML page and not JSON.

As the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662145/use-facebook-graphapi-or-fql-to-get-facebook-activity-log) has pointed out, it will take multiple Graph API AND FQL queries just to retrieve the objects that are in your Activity Log.  You would then need to spin through those to determine if it is something you Liked or not.